# sonarqube error while execute scan(java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerErrorjava.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError)

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

when I try to scan my code with sonarqube, I got below errors :

```
myMac% sonar-scanner
INFO: Scanner configuration file: /usr/local/Cellar/sonar-scanner/4.3.0.2102/libexec/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: /Users/jack/Desktop/XX/Projects/XXXX/Project/sonar-project.properties
INFO: SonarScanner 4.3.0.2102
INFO: Java 13-ea Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
INFO: Mac OS X 10.13.6 x86_64
INFO: User cache: /Users/jack/.sonar/cache
INFO: Scanner configuration file: /usr/local/Cellar/sonar-scanner/4.3.0.2102/libexec/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: ...path/project/sonar-project.properties
INFO: Analyzing on SonarQube server 7.9.4
INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
INFO: Load global settings
INFO: Load global settings (done) | time=87ms
INFO: Server id: BF41A1F2-AXRr6UD6H1saInOfj60W
INFO: User cache: /Users/jzhu321/.sonar/cache
INFO: Load/download plugins
INFO: Load plugins index
INFO: Load/download plugins (done) | time=70ms
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 1.609s
INFO: Final Memory: 4M/27M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.google.gson.internal.reflect.ReflectionAccessor.<clinit>(ReflectionAccessor.java:36)
        at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor.<init>(ConstructorConstructor.java:51)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.<init>(Gson.java:205)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.<init>(Gson.java:185)
        at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.ScannerPluginInstaller.listInstalledPlugins(ScannerPluginInstaller.java:104)
        at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.ScannerPluginInstaller.loadPlugins(ScannerPluginInstaller.java:76)
        at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.ScannerPluginInstaller.installRemotes(ScannerPluginInstaller.java:60)
        at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.ScannerPluginRepository.start(ScannerPluginRepository.java:59)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.StartableCloseableSafeLifecyleStrategy.start(StartableCloseableSafeLifecyleStrategy.java:40)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1016)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1009)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:767)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:122)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecute(Batch.java:73)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:189)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute(EmbeddedScanner.java:138)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:112)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:75)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "13-ea"
        at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:68)
        at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:658)
        at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:776)
        at com.google.gson.util.VersionUtils.determineMajorJavaVersion(VersionUtils.java:28)
        at com.google.gson.util.VersionUtils.<clinit>(VersionUtils.java:24)
        ... 32 more
ERROR: 
ERROR: Re-run SonarScanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

I think maybe the version of my JDK gose wrong ? these erros show no tips or tell how to resolve it, and I have no idea what to do now. can any one helps?

Update:
I upgraded the SonarScanner to the latest version, bug I got some new errors here:

```
INFO: Scanner configuration file: /usr/local/Cellar/sonar-scanner/4.3.0.2102/libexec/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: /Users/jzhu321/Desktop/PwC/Projects/Risk_Command/RC_UI_NEW/Digital_RC/RC_UI/sonar-project.properties
INFO: SonarScanner 4.4.0.2170
INFO: Java 11.0.3 AdoptOpenJDK (64-bit)
INFO: Mac OS X 10.13.6 x86_64
INFO: User cache: /Users/jzhu321/.sonar/cache
INFO: Scanner configuration file: /usr/local/Cellar/sonar-scanner/4.3.0.2102/libexec/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: /Users/jzhu321/Desktop/PwC/Projects/Risk_Command/RC_UI_NEW/Digital_RC/RC_UI/sonar-project.properties
INFO: Analyzing on SonarQube server 7.9.4
INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "en_US"
INFO: Load global settings
INFO: Load global settings (done) | time=109ms
INFO: Server id: BF41A1F2-AXRsELIlICCBnUbeLAM-
INFO: User cache: /Users/jzhu321/.sonar/cache
INFO: Load/download plugins
INFO: Load plugins index
INFO: Load plugins index (done) | time=89ms
INFO: Load/download plugins (done) | time=251ms
INFO: Process project properties
INFO: Execute project builders
INFO: Execute project builders (done) | time=3ms
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 2.829s
INFO: Final Memory: 5M/24M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectLock
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:65)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:678)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.getComponentByType(ComponentContainer.java:281)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doBeforeStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:153)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:134)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:122)
        at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.doAfterStart(GlobalContainer.java:141)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:136)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:122)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecute(Batch.java:73)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:189)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute(EmbeddedScanner.java:138)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:112)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:75)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.api.batch.fs.internal.DefaultInputProject
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:65)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:632)
        at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
        at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:63)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: en_US
        at java.base/java.nio.charset.Charset.forName(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonar.api.batch.fs.internal.AbstractProjectOrModule.initEncoding(AbstractProjectOrModule.java:76)
        at org.sonar.api.batch.fs.internal.AbstractProjectOrModule.<init>(AbstractProjectOrModule.java:69)
        at org.sonar.api.batch.fs.internal.DefaultInputProject.<init>(DefaultInputProject.java:37)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.InputProjectProvider.provide(InputProjectProvider.java:47)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.invokeMethod(MethodInjector.java:129)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.access$000(MethodInjector.java:39)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector$2.run(MethodInjector.java:113)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.decorateComponentInstance(MethodInjector.java:120)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.CompositeInjector.decorateComponentInstance(CompositeInjector.java:58)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.Reinjector.reinject(Reinjector.java:142)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ProviderAdapter.getComponentInstance(ProviderAdapter.java:96)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:63)
        ... 36 more
```

Update2 :

above error is due to the path name , change

```
sonar.sources=.
```

to

```
sonar.sources=./
```

will solve the problem.

Comment: Sonar tried to parse `13-ea` to an `int`. Do you use an early access version of java 13? According to [this thread](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/openjdk8-jre-java-lang-exceptionininitializererror/7962/3), this is not supported.

Comment: According to [This Gson issue](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1469) there is s workaround: set the gson version in the sonar plugin to `2.8.5` or just update SonarLint...

Comment: @dan1st I'd like to try your advice, can you tell me where or how to set the gson version in the sonar plugin? (it's a react project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gson (as a part of Sonar) tried to parse the string `13-ea` to an `int` while trying to find out the java version. According to [this](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/openjdk8-jre-java-lang-exceptionininitializererror/7962/3) thread, this was not supported in March, 2013.

According to [this Gson issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63787418/sonarqube-error-while-execute-scanjava-lang-exceptionininitializererrorjava-lan#) the issue was fixed in gson version 2.8.5.

[This SonarLint pull request](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarlint-core/pull/245) fixd the issue on SonarLint's side by updating Gson. It was merged in April, 2019.

If you look at the [SonarLint Release page](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarlint-core/releases?after=4.4.0.2561), you can clearly see that the next version after the merge is `4.3.0.2475` while you use `SonarScanner 4.3.0.2102`.

Just update Sonar scanner to the latest version and you should be fine.

You can download the latest version of `sonar-scanner` for MacOS from [here](https://binaries.sonarsource.com/Distribution/sonar-scanner-cli/sonar-scanner-cli-4.4.0.2170-macosx.zip)

Another option would to just use another non-early-access java version.